# What resources exist for information about ancestors affected by the Expulsion of the Acadians?

Tags: united-states, military-records, 18th-century, canada, army

I believe I had ancestors in [Acadia who were expelled by the British](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_of_the_Acadians) in the mid-18th century.

Are there any surviving records from this event? Where can they be found?

Answer (score 3):

For a good beginning there is a good bibliography at the end of the Wikipedia article on [Expulsion of the Acadians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_of_the_Acadians).

You also might contact Acadian researcher Yvon L. Cyr via his website [Acadian.org](http://www.acadian.org/author.html).